# Where is this file supposed to be?

Tags: macos, git

When I looked on my desktop I noticed the file "git-credential-osxkeychain" is on there.
I'm assuming it's a git file, but don't know how it managed to end up on my desktop. Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: I assume you got the file from here https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain. Follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: I have no idea where it came from really. I don't remember ever doing anything that involved it. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's supposed to be in /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

Look at this post:
[Trying to install git on OSX: cannont exec 'git-credential-osxkeychain': Permission denied`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867946/trying-to-install-git-on-osx-cannont-exec-git-credential-osxkeychain-permiss)